# How to give ubuntu its own bios entry that doesn't just open grub?

Tags: uefi, bios

I would appreciate some help here, lol. Im new to linux, and i need ubuntu to have its own entry for… **reasons** edit: i want it for use for win to linux. The ubuntu version is 22.0.4? Or 22.04 I'm not sure.

Comment: What is the point of having an ubuntu BIOS/UEFI entry if not to boot from it? If you don't want to see a grub display, that's a separate grub configuration issue that has nothing to do with the ubuntu BIOS/UEFI entry, which must be present.

Comment: If you expect to receive help you'd need to provide sufficient details. As your question is currently written it's unclear what you're asking. What is happening, what do you expect to happen? Ubuntu version? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1478942/edit) your question to add relevant information.

Comment: @PaulBenson its for win to linux on github.

Comment: @mook765 I’ve added the requested details.

Comment: Ubuntu uses `grub` by default for its bootstrapping; yes you can replace grub with `lilo` etc, but grub has more features making it easier when things go wrong. I suspect you're trying to bypass that step though. FYI: Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format for main products, ie. 22.04 = 2022.April release, with specialist *snap* only products using *year* (22 = Ubuntu Core 22 or 2022 release; always 2000 is subtracted from year).